# WSO2 virtual machine image

Tags: security, wso2, virtual-machine, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I am looking for a CEP tool to start off with my project about monitoring real time network intrusion detection system's logs. I found about WSO2 but I didn't succeed in finding vm image having WSO2 installed and configured to download and practice. 
Can anyone give me some useful links regarding `WSO2 CEP` including its thorough examples and VM image download link? Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by  VM image download link? do you want wso2 cep download link?

Comment: I want a VM image with WSO2 CEP installed and configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2CEP does not come in VM, its quite easy to setup, just unzip and run `sh <CEP_HOME>/bin/wso2server.sh` or `<CEP_HOME>/bin/wso2server.bat`

See getting stated video http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/#Getting-Started

And docs https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/WSO2+Complex+Event+Processor+Documentation

Comment: Thanky you, that's what all I was looking for.